# how can I find the remote address of a continuous UDP stream

Tags: c#, .net, udp, ip-address

For those of you who play MW2 on the PC you know it is plagued by hackers and cheaters.  I would like to create a solution where the host of a multi player game can selectively firewall out a cheater.
The problem I am running into is I do not know how to locate remote IPs that are sending or receiving UDP packets.
Netstat will only show the listeners on my local machine.
`IPGlobalProperties` does not have any methods I can use either as UDP is connectionless.

How can I go about finding remote IPs of UDP packets?
I would like to code a solution using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to write a network sniffer to start with, see this CodeProject [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

here is my source code for the admin tool i made, vac will ban you for it
it uses winpcap to read the game network traffic, and scans for key packets.
then stores the name and ip address of each user connected to you.
as well as provides an http interface to kick/ban players.

works on xp32, vista 32 64 and win7 32 64

http://sof.adivinedude.com/downloads/index.php?dir=&file=COD_ADMIN_v2.4_source_code.zip